# service not autoscaling to zero in cloud run

Tags: next.js, google-cloud-run

A service is running for last 12 hours in Cloud Run , however have not sent any request after first hour. I read that there is no predictable time frame before which service is scaled to zero in FAQ, but I would assume after 10 hours the green tick mark should go off against service name in Cloud Run dashboard as it also says 0 req/sec for last 10 hours ?

Service is behind a custom domain that is new.

From logs , I can see below requests intermittently - seems like crawlers are making some requests - is that the reason service does not scale to zero ?

```
2019-05-04T01:57:10.661674ZGET200 764 B 4 ms Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)  /_next/static/CobVVFSUIaptTFTVGYam1/pages/index.js
2019-05-04T01:57:15.349339ZGET200 22.46 KB 6 ms Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)  /_next/static/runtime/main-fd73dbd6f398b7b886ec.js
2019-05-04T01:57:15.490689ZGET200 1.83 KB 5 ms Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)  /_next/static/runtime/webpack-a79426b5e11f0ba5879d.js
2019-05-04T01:57:19.993381ZGET200 2.8 KB 4 ms Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)  /_next/static/CobVVFSUIaptTFTVGYam1/pages/_app.js
2019-05-04T01:57:20.071521ZGET200 180.46 KB 6 ms Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)  /_next/static/chunks/commons.6b84ece70b270c5da3e5.js
```

=====
EDIT

I do see after 7 hours of inactivity, it issues following lines in log

```
Container terminated by the container manager on signal 9.
```

Comment: The green checkmark next to a Cloud Run app just means it is deployed successfully. Cloud Run doesn't tell you how many instances of an app is running at any time. When your app will scale to zero depends on a lot of factors like the capacity at Google Cloud, so you should not actually worry about your app not scaling to zero since you’re not paying for it. In your case, it seems like bingbot is sending you requests (as expected, since it's a website), so you'll be charged for those requests. Use a `robots.txt` if you don't want to be visited by bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking at the green check mark in the Cloud Console? That merely means that the service is ready to serve traffic. It doesn't mean that an instance is actively provisioned.

Comment: oh did not know that, how else can we know if it is really up ? is it logs mainly ?

Comment: When you see this message: `Container terminated by the container manager on signal 9.` the container shuts down. You will then see another message when the container launches again. You can setup Stackdriver monitoring to track metrics. Memory for example. 0 memory means no container is running. This gives you a graph to see how many containers are running at any point in time.

Comment: You should not _care_ if a container is up or not on Cloud Run. That's why you’re not supposed to "know if it's really up". Container lifecycle is abstracted away from you and you should care about what happens during a request.